# An inn/tavern with no innkeeper built inside a cavern with access outside the fortress walls: NPC behavior, impact?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[image]
<sup>Left hand side: From an entrance outside the fortress walls, in the caverns, (1) an inn/tavern location, followed by a (2) passage to a (3) temple location. Right hand side: some events/interactions took place.</sup>

I'm trying to ascertain the NPC+(non-operated)inn/tavern+cavern+entrance outside fortress walls mechanics and the impact on the fortress.

---

The [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Visitors) states that visitors come in one of five occupations: performer, mercenary, bandit, monster slayer, or diplomat; the Lord Consort NPC is identified as a "warrior".

- Is that a *mercenary* or *monster slayer* or what?

The [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Visitors) states that: *Monster hunters visit [inns](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tavern) to hunt monsters
   within the caverns. Once they are granted long term residency they
   will occasionally go down into the caverns on their own to hunt. As
   of 0.42.04 they might be bugged as nobody other than Toady has
   reported seeing them, but supposedly their requirements for arrival
   are having opened the caverns.*

- What does "grant long term residency" mean; do you need to accept a
  petition for this behavior to occur; does the inn need to be operated for this to occur and will the NPC hunting include hunting Forgotten Beasts?

Comment: 1) We don't need that many supplemental links.  2) Your questions are all over the place.  Please focus on a single, specific issue you are having.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in one.  It's usually frowned upon to do this, as it makes gathering an answer difficult and arduous.

Answer (score 3):

A warrior is mercenary. When a NPC wants to stay at your fort "P: Petitions" will flash at the top of the screen. If you press P it brings up the petitions screen. a will grant their request and b will deny it. "Grant Long Term Residence" means they will stay stay at the fortress and work for you depending on their job in return for housing. Warriors you can put in squads, bards and performers will perform, scholars will study. You need to have a bed attached to a location for housing for them. You don't need a tavern keeper for this. Lord and Lady Consorts are mercenaries. Rarely NPCs will ask to become a citizen rather than just stay and they will become a regular dwarf in your fort if you accept.